# gcc object passing by value or by address

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, parameter-passing, calling-convention

We have this simple class:

```
class MyStr
{
public:
    MyStr() { }
    wchar_t* pStr;
};
```

and this code that uses it:

```
MyStr ms1, ms2;
ms1.pStr = L"MyStr!"; 
ms2.pStr = L"MyStr2!";

wchar_t buffer[100];
swprintf(buffer, 100, L"%ls - %ls", ms1, ms2);
```

The assembly that pushes ms1 and ms2 onto the stack looks like:

```
FF B5 24 FE FF FF    push DWORD PTR [ebp-0x1dc] 
FF B5 20 FE FF FF    push DWORD PTR [ebp-0x1e0]
```

It is actually pushing the the values/content of MyStr (which in this case is just pStr) onto the stack.

If we change MyStr to just add a simple destructor:

```
class MyStr
{
public:
    MyStr() { }
    ~MyStr() { }
    wchar_t* pStr;
};
```

now the address of ms1 and ms2 are getting passed, instead of their values/contents.

```
8D 85 24 FE FF FF    lea eax,[ebp-0x1dc] 
50                   push eax 
8D 85 20 FE FF FF    lea eax,[ebp-0x1e0] 
50                   push eax
```

Visual Studio on Windows gives the same result both ways (always passes values/contents), but gcc on Linux gives these two different results.

1. Why?
2. What can we do to keep the destructor but pass by value instead of by reference/address?

The thing we cannot do is change the swprintf line - there are many thousands of them and we are trying to avoid changing them.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations?

Comment: No optimizations in either case.

Comment: Argument that `swprintf` accepts is limited. and class object is not one of them.

Comment: It accepts it and works perfectly if there is no destructor, because ultimately it receives a wchar_t*

Comment: Your definition of "perfect" is nonstandard.

Comment: OK, non-standard but works on two popular platforms with two popular compilers.  But that's besides the point. The question is why.

Comment: From [variadic_arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) *"Only arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, pointer to member, and class type arguments are allowed."*.

Comment: The `printf` family of functions takes good ol' C-style variable arguments. It will eat anything and attempt to consume it according to the rules in the format string. `MyStr`  just happens to contain a c-style string, which satisfies `%ls`, so you dodge the undefined behaviour bullet here, but it's still undefined behaviour.

Comment: BUT, it only works if there is no destructor.  Why should the destructor cause a fundamental difference in how the parameter is passed?

Comment: It's up to the compiler how to implement passing a struct through `...`, as long as `va_arg(ap, MyStr)` does the opposite to get it back.  But `swprintf` calls `va_arg(ap, const wchar_t*)`, not `va_arg(ap, MyStr)`.  If those happen to do the same thing, it's just luck.

Comment: That I don't know. Godbolt looks at the code and runs away screaming: https://godbolt.org/g/2H6HQO. GCC 4.8 compiles it, but spits warnings.

Comment: I assume you're aware that your code is undefined behaviour and you are asking about how to "control" the undefined aspects?

Comment: Once I add the destructor, GCC 4.8 gives me "error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'class MyStr' through '...' " Adding the destructor did change the layout, or the compiler's perception of the layout, enough that it's refusing to compile. What compiler and version are you using under linux?

Comment: As undefined as it might be, this is the principle that Visual Studio's CString class uses to work with printf statements.  Granted, they control the compiler so can define how they want it to work.  But it works well in Linux too.  Except when you have a destructor.  What about a destructor changes how an object is passed?

Comment: @user4581301, I'm using gcc 5.4.0 on Ubuntu

Comment: @user581301, if you add the length to the swprintf, it compiles fine in the Godbolt example.  I updated the code above to show that.

Comment: Adding a desructor means the class is not [trivially destructable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Trivial_destructor). If the class is not trivially destructable, it is not [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable). If it is not trivially copyable, it will be harder to pass by value because that requires a copy. This may be the cause of your finding. In https://godbolt.org/g/1ViJXG  I've removed the problem of varargs to make a simpler example. Comment out the destructor and watch the fun.

Comment: A second thought, re-asking with code like the second godbolt example may get a better breed of answer because it doesn't have the distraction of invoking undefined behaviour. Someone who knows compilers and assembly a lot better than I do may pop up a, "Oh. That's because <insert explanation here>."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may resort to MACRO

```
// Forward call to your method
#define swprintf(...) my_swprintf(__VA_ARGS__)

// Your class
class MyStr
{
public:
    MyStr() { }
    ~MyStr() { }
    const wchar_t* pStr;
};


// helper function to "fix" parameters
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value || std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>
normalize(T t) { return t; } // Default one which does nothing

// Fix for your class to return its member.
const wchar_t* normalize(const MyStr& t) { return t.pStr; }

// Your function which (re-)forward to real swprintf with fixed parameter
// Extra parent do avoid macro substitution
template <typename ... Ts>
auto my_swprintf(wchar_t* buffer, const wchar_t* format, const Ts&... args)
{
    return (swprintf)(buffer, format, normalize(args)...);
}
```

Comment: It's not a macro, strictly spoken, is it?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: I define `swprintf` as "macro function".

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thanks. Btw, does the bracketing of `(swprintf)` inside the `my_swprintf` function prevent the expansion of the macro? If so, I was not aware of that mechanism (and would have `#undef`ed it).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: As I wrote in comment, *"// Extra parent do avoid macro substitution"*, so yes `(swprintf)` avoid the expansion of macro function.